# Prove that these two definitions are equivalent

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/1012195#1012195) I have used that \begin{equation}\sin x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\end{equation}
Nwe my question is that how can it be shown that the definition of $\sin x$ using the notion of perpendiculars and hypotenuse is equivalent to this definition?

As has been standard to proving that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent one first needs to show that $A \implies B$ and then $A \impliedby B$. I thought about applying this for sometime but in either case I am lost. Any ideas?

**Note:-** I have also read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799277/equivalence-of-the-two-cosine-definitions) but the answer seemed to me to be circular. So, even if the question is almost similar to the previously linked question, I posted it as a different question because my requirements are different.

Comment: [My answer to a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) describes a geometric interpretation of the series.

Comment: @Blue: I have read it but it isn't useful for my purpose because you use the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$ which is what I need to prove.

Comment: @Lucian: Are you aware that you linked the same question to which gave an answer and from which this question arose?

Comment: Sorry. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863072) was the link that I wanted to post, but was unable to locate it at the time.

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1001053/72031