# Infinite Sum without using $\sin\pi$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

What's a purely algebraic way to prove that $\pi-\frac{\pi^3}{3!}+\frac{\pi^5}{5!}-\dots=0$? I'm sure that the first step is to write $\pi=4-\frac43+\frac45-\dots$, but I haven't been bold enough to complete the algebra, nor do I think it is feasible. :(

I guess in general, what's the algebraic way to prove that the Taylor series of $\sin x$ converges to the geometric definition of $\sin x$?

Comment: How do you define $\pi$? This question may also be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233961/how-can-you-derive-sinx-sinx2-pi-from-the-taylor-series-for-sinx

Comment: To address the first question, your series for $\pi$ doesn't converge absolutely, so you can't use the Cauchy product with itself to calculate $\pi^{2}$. It therefore seems unlikely the proposed approach is viable.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about an "algebraic proof." A direct power series substitution using the power series for $\arctan$ would need to give you:

$$\sin(4\arctan(x))=\frac{4x(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{8x}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{4x}{1+x^2}=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)x^{2n+1}$$

That's gonna be messy but not necessarily impossible to show. Note the series does not converge when $x=1$, but arguments can be made as $x\to 1-$.

The key to the second part is to prove that $\exp(ix)=\cos x + i\sin x$, where $\exp(z)=\sum_k z^k/k!$. One way to prove this is to show that $f(x)=1+ix$ is "close enough" to $\mathrm{cis}(x)=\cos x + i\sin x$ when $x$ is near zero so that $\lim f(x/n)^n = \lim \mathrm{cis}(x/n)^n$. But you can prove that $\mathrm{cis}(x/n)^n=\mathrm{cis}(x)$ by induction, and to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x/n)^n = \exp(ix)$.

The "close enough" part of the proof - that $\mathrm{cis}(x)=1+xi + o(x)$ - can be made geometric.

[Here's an answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933) that covers how close "close enough" needs to be to get this result.

**Outline of the geometric part of the proof**

> First show that $\sin x<x$ for $x$ positive, since $\sin x$ is the shortest distance from a point $(\cos x,\sin x)$ to the $x$-axis, and $x$ is the distance from the same point along the circle.
>
> Then show that $1-\cos x =\frac{\sin ^2 x}{1+\cos x}<\sin^2 x<x^2$.
>
> The last step is harder - showing that $x-\sin x$ is "small enough." It requires a theorem about convex sets - the shortest path between two points on the surface of a convex set which never enters the interior must lie entirely on that convex set. This is sort of intuitive.
>
> From that geometric result, you can show that $\tan x > x$, and hence that $x-\sin x < \tan x - \sin x < \sin x\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x} = o(x)$ when $x$ near zero.

**More on algebraic approach**

The power series approach is going to be brutal. Let's just try the case $\sin 2\arctan x = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}=2\sum_{n} (-1)^n x^{2n+1}$.

Now, for $k$ odd, the contribution of $\arctan^k x$ to the coefficient $x^n$ in $\sin 2\arctan x$ is in terms of the set $P_{n,k}=\{(n_1,\dots,n_k)\mid n_i\text{ odd, } \sum n_i=n\}$. The contribution of $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ is $$\frac{(-1)^{(k-1)/2}4^k}{k!}\prod_i \frac{(-1)^{(n_i-1)/2}}{n_i} = \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2}4^k}{k!\prod n_i}$$

Basically, you need that:

$$\sum_{n_1+\cdots + n_k=n} \frac{4^{k-1}}{k!n_1n_2\cdots n_k} = n$$

where the $n$ is odd and the sum is over partitions under the condition that each $n_i$ is odd.

It's not at all clear how summing these is even going to be an integer.

It's  easy to verify for small $n$. $n=1$ is trivial. For $n=3$, the partitions are $(3)$ and $(1,1,1)$ which gives $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4^2}{6}=3$. For $n=5$, the partitions are $(5),(3,1,1),(1,3,1),(1,1,3),(1,1,1,1,1)$ and you get:

$$\frac{1}{5} + 3\cdot \frac{4^2}{3!\cdot 3} + \frac{4^4}{5!}=5$$

An interesting fact is that this equality seems to be true for $n$ even, as well (still with the condition that the $n_i$ are odd.) I wonder if there is a probability explanation for this - some process for choosing partitions of $n$ into odd integers where the probability of getting $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ is $\frac{4^{k}}{n k!n_1\dots n_k}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Along the circle of equation $x^2+y^2=1$, the arc length is (in the first  quadrant)

$$\theta=\int_0^y\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\arcsin(y)$$ so that $y$ is the geometric definition of the sine.

This relation can also be written as the differential equation

$$y'^2(\theta)+y^2(\theta)=1,$$

which by derivation gives

$$2y''(\theta)y'(\theta)+2y'(\theta)y(\theta)=0,$$

or $$y''(\theta)=-y(\theta).$$

With $y(0)=0$, this leads to the well-known Taylor development.