# Period of sine and cosine defined by Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, pi

I was reading how to define the sine and cosine functions via their Taylor series. I think the hardest part is showing their periodicity. Some questions and answers to this include [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233961/how-can-you-derive-sinx-sinx2-pi-from-the-taylor-series-for-sinx/1233969) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how-to-prove-periodicity-of-sinx-or-cosx-starting-from-the-taylor-seri). I understood how to show it. The key part is to *define* the number $\pi/2$ by the smallest positive number whose cosine is zero.

However, I could not find any proof that this definition of $\pi$ indeed coincides the geometric definition of $\pi$ in our mind, i.e., the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter. How can I prove this? If this question is a duplicate, I would appreciate it if you let me know. Thank you.